# Smooth injective function has somewhere injective derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Been working on some differential geometry and am needing a more elementary result from multivariate calculus + linear algebra, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Here goes:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth and injective function. Does there exist a point $x\in U$ such that the derivative matrix $df|_x$ is injective?